# Recyclerview won't show after coming back to activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a cart activity; the cart items get loaded in the recycler view (which works fine the first time). If I press back from the cart (which takes to the product page) and come to cart again, the items don't show. I believe the items get loaded, but don't display.

```
class CartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var cartRef: DatabaseReference
lateinit var txtvwCartTotalAmount: TextView
lateinit var imgbtnCartMinus: ImageButton
lateinit var imgbtnCartPlus: ImageButton
lateinit var adapter: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>
private var currentUserPhone = ""
var cartTotal = 0
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
var isIncrease = false
var isDecrease = false



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart)

    try {
        cartRef = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .reference.child("User View Cart")

        var sharedPreferences =
            getSharedPreferences("name", MODE_PRIVATE)
        currentUserPhone = sharedPreferences.getString("phone", "")!!

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recvwCartList)
        txtvwCartTotalAmount = findViewById(R.id.txtvwCartTotalAmount)

        val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
            .setQuery(cartRef.child(currentUserPhone).child("Products"), Cart::class.java)
            .build()

        // to fetch price and quantity to update total cart value before setting the adapter
        options.snapshots.addChangeEventListener(object : ChangeEventListener {
            override fun onChildChanged(
                type: ChangeEventType,
                snapshot: DataSnapshot,
                newIndex: Int,
                oldIndex: Int
            ) {
                var price = 0
                var quantity = 0
                var amount = 0
                var productName = ""

                var dataMap = snapshot.value as MutableMap<Any, Any>

                var productNameKV = dataMap["productName"]
                productName = productNameKV.toString()

                var priceKV = dataMap["price"]
                price = Integer.parseInt(priceKV.toString())

                var quantityKV = dataMap["quantity"]
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityKV.toString())

                amount = (price * quantity)

                if (isIncrease) {
                    cartTotal += price
                } else if (isDecrease) {
                    cartTotal -= price
                } else {
                    cartTotal += amount
                }

                txtvwCartTotalAmount.text =
                    resources.getString(R.string.rupee_symbol, cartTotal.toString())

                isIncrease = false
                isDecrease = false

            }

            override fun onDataChanged() {
                // A full update has been received and processed.
                // Here's where you would use `snapshots` and process stuff
            }

            override fun onError(e: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

        adapter =
            object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(options) {

                override fun onBindViewHolder(
                    holder: CartViewHolder,
                    position: Int,
                    model: Cart
                ) {
                    //initializations
                    imgbtnCartMinus = holder.ibCartMinus
                    imgbtnCartPlus = holder.ibCartPlus


                    //assigning values
                    holder.tvProductName.text = model.productName
                    holder.tvProductPrice.text =
                        resources.getString(R.string.rupee_symbol, model.price)

                    holder.tvCartProductQuantity.text = model.quantity

                    var productAmount =
                        Integer.parseInt(model.price) * Integer.parseInt(holder.tvCartProductQuantity.text.toString())

                    holder.tvCartProductAmount.text = productAmount.toString()
                    Glide.with(holder.ivCartProductImage.context)
                        .load(model.imageUrl)
                        .into(holder.ivCartProductImage)


                    //redirect to product details page on item click
                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                        var productID = model.productID
                        val intent =
                            Intent(this@CartActivity, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("productID", productID)

                        startActivity(intent)
                    }

                    holder.ibCartPlus.setOnClickListener {
                        increaseQuantityInCart(
                            model.productID,
                            position,
                            holder.tvCartProductQuantity.text.toString()
                        )
                    }

                    holder.ibCartMinus.setOnClickListener {
                        decreaseQuantityInCart(
                            model.productID,
                            position,
                            holder.tvCartProductQuantity.text.toString()
                        )
                    }

                    holder.tvRemoveProduct.setOnClickListener {
                        removeProductFromCart(position, model.productID)
                    }

                }

                override fun onCreateViewHolder(
                    parent: ViewGroup,
                    viewType: Int
                ): CartViewHolder {
                    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.cart_product_layout, parent, false)
                    return CartViewHolder(view)
                }

            }

        initializeRecyclerView()


        //onBackPressed()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}

private fun initializeRecyclerView(){
    var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    //layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    adapter.startListening()
}
```

activity_cart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:elevation="9dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvwCartTotalAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvwProceedAndPay"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/appGreen"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Proceed And Pay"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recvwCartList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Try debugging ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not familar with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, but you do everything in the onCreate. It looks like the activity is created when you enter the first time. When you go back and enter it again, it was not destroyed, so that the onCreate callback is not called. Try to move the data update to onResume.

Answer (score 0):

So what was needed was:

Changing this:

```
private fun initializeRecyclerView(){
var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
//layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
adapter.startListening()
}
```

to this:

```
private fun initializeRecyclerView(){
var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

//layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
//recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true) //---> removed
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager // setting layoutManager after the adapter is set
adapter.startListening()
}
```